# Make Dynamic IP from ISP like Static

Tags: networking, dhcp, isp, dhcp-server

As the title says, is it possible to have a dynamic IP from an ISP and make it renew when the lease is up to the same IP? I ask because I would like to run a Home-Page and a VPN + FTP service on the IP.

Comment: No, not unless the ISP allows it explicitly. The general approach to addressing this is to use a dynamically updated DNS name via a DDNS provider. then your router or a computer in the lan can update the DNS provider whenever your external IP changes.

Answer (score 0):

**Generally, no, you cannot.**

You would need to pay the ISP an extra amount to have a static IP address. The IP address allocated to you cannot be chosen by the client, but is allocated explicitly by the service provider on every connection. Just to reaffirm the point, consider what would happen if you lost service due to some reason, and in the mean-time your IP address was allocated to someone else. Now when you come back online, you simply *must* have a different IP address from the earlier one.

You can consider an alternative by using any free DDNS service.